# How to upgrade stack version 0.1.10 to 1.3.2 in Linux

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Executing command `stack upgrade` stores stack version 1.3 in the directory `~/.local/bin`. How should I make this as default stack in the machine. `stack upgrade --git` doesn't help too.

This is my path -
`bash: /home/sudha/bin:/home/sudha/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory`

Comment: Simply prepend `~/.local/bin` to your PATH.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to work now without doing it, I closed the terminal after `stack upgrade` and opened a new terminal.

Comment: Instead of closing and opening a new terminal you can enter this to refresh your environment `. ~/.profile`.